# Xcode6 で10.4u.sdkを使用する

Tags: objective-c, xcode6

Xcode6 で10.4u.sdkを利用してコンパイルを行う必要が出てきました。

10.4u.sdkを別途用意し、GCC4.0を使用できるようにしてコンパイルしました。
ターゲットのプロジェクトはコンパイルに成功するのですが、Testerのプロジェクトで以下のファイルでコンパイルエラーが発生します。

```
・SenTestCase.h
　・Expected ';' before ')' token.
　・Expected type-specifier before 'NSUInteger'
　・Expected ')' before 'NSUInteger'

・SenTestLog.h
　・Expected ';' before '(' token.
　・Expected ')' before numeric constant.
　・Expected type-specifier before numeric constant
　・Expected ';' before numeric constant.
　・Expected identifier before numeric constant.
```

Tester以外のターゲットはコンパイルエラーになっていません。
このエラーの原因が分からず困っています。

「SenTestCase.h」は「SenTestingKit.framework」に含まれるヘッダファイルです。

具体的には、上記ファイルの以下の部分がエラーとなっています。

```
- (void) beforeTestIteration:(NSUInteger)iteration selector:(SEL)testMethod; // 165行目
- (void) afterTestIteration:(NSUInteger)iteration selector:(SEL)testMethod; // 166行目

- (NSUInteger) numberOfTestIterationsForTestWithSelector:(SEL)testMethod; // 169行目
```

どなたか原因が分かる方や、同じような経験をされた事がある方がいらっしゃいましたら、
情報を頂けると大変助かります。

Comment: エラーメッセージ内の SenTestCash.h などのファイルは公開できませんか? またエラーメッセージ内にファイルの行数を示す文言はなかったでしょうか? それがあるならば、該当する行の±5行程度だけでも公開していただければ、良い解答が付きやすくなると期待できます。

Comment: 回答として投稿されていた補足情報を、質問の方に移しました。